# validation of entire row with particular columns using spring mvc

Tags: java

I want to validate particular row with specific columns from excell sheet.It returns List and it contains the specific columns data.

```
public static List<Integer> validatespec(){
    xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

The method returns columns (2,5,12,16).If that row doesn't contain spec value it returns error like please mention particular column spec value.

[image]

In the image row 3 doesn't contain spc then it shows error and row 4 doesn't contain size it shows error

Comment: How is this related to angularjs? What did you tried?

Comment: Basically this spring mvc with angularjs.what I am trying is when the spc row(2) is not empty and contain spc spring we can store the data otherwise to display pop window like proceed button with warning message